# JS condition change class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, conditional-statements

How should i write the Javascript to add a new class (.indiceLow, indiceMedium, indiceHigh) to my ID polIndice depending of the number i display.

They should be display like this:

- number < 50 = .indiceLow
- 50 < number < 100 = .indiceMedium
- number > 100 = .indiceHigh

```css
.indice {
  background-color:#F5F5F5;
  width: 50%;
  text-align:center;
  padding:10px;
}

.indiceLow {
  background-color: #BBCF4C; 
  color:#fff;
}
.indiceMedium {
  background-color: #EEC20B;
  color:#fff;
}
.indiceHigh {
  background-color: #F29305;
  color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="polIndice" class="indice">(number)</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Document ready, read text of element, have if/else if/else, add class.

Comment: You may start here [http://www.w3schools.com/js/](http://www.w3schools.com/js/) and [http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need just `innerHTML/innerText` method and set of conditions. No jQuery needed.

```
var el = document.getElementById('polIndice');
var val = parseInt(el.innerText);
var class_name;

if (val < 50) {
    class_name = 'indiceLow';
} else if (val < 100) {
    class_name = 'indiceMedium';
} else {
    class_name = 'indiceHigh';
}

el.className += ' ' + class_name;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hyuu5w5z/

Comment: Thanks, it is perfect for what i need.

Answer (score 0):

I create a function for you but i don't think you really need this...

```
function addIndice(elemId, num) {
    var classNam = ['indiceLow', 'indiceMedium', 'indiceHigh'];

    num = typeof(num) == "number" ? num : parseInt(num);

    var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);

    if(num < 50) {
        elem.className += " " + classNam[0];
    }else if(num >= 50 && num <= 100) {
        elem.className += " " + classNam[1];
    }else if(num > 100) {
        elem.className += " " + classNam[2];
    }
}
```

With the HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            .indice {
              background-color:#F5F5F5;
              width: 50%;
              text-align:center;
              padding:10px;
            }

            .indiceLow {
              background-color: #BBCF4C; 
              color:#fff;
            }
            .indiceMedium {
              background-color: #EEC20B;
              color:#fff;
            }
            .indiceHigh {
              background-color: #F29305;
              color:#fff;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="polIndice" class="indice"></div>

        <!-- Script at the end -->
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            function addIndice(elemId, num) {
                var classNam = ['indiceLow', 'indiceMedium', 'indiceHigh'];

                num = typeof(num) == "number" ? num : parseInt(num);

                var elem = document.getElementById(elemId);

                if(num < 50) {
                    elem.className += " " + classNam[0];
                }else if(num >= 50 && num <= 100) {
                    elem.className += " " + classNam[1];
                }else if(num > 100) {
                    elem.className += " " + classNam[2];
                }
            }

            addIndice('polIndice', 10);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @elcid9: what if `num` will be `-1`? `50`? `100`? What do you mean `else {return false}` should do in your code?